# Split matrix expression into multiple lines

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, expression-manipulation, index

Given a matrix expression

```
testm = {a + b, c + d, e};

{# , testm[[ # ]] // Simplify} & /@ Range[ Length[testm] ] // MatrixForm
```

\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a+b \\ 2 & c+d \\ 3 & e \\\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
I want to rewrite this as
\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}1.1 & a \\1.2 & b \\2.1 & c \\2.2 & d \\3 & e \\\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

How do I do this?
Eventually, I want to extend this to a more complicated case where I have \begin{equation}(a+b) = A exp[I(k + l)m(n + o + p\ q)] Cos(r \ s)+A exp(I (k + l) m (n + o + p \ q)) Sin(t \ u)\end{equation} displaying the cosine term next to 1.1 and the sine term next to 1.2 .

Comment: Is 1.1 the real number 1.1?

Comment: no, just a subindex; meaning the first summand of (a+b)

Answer (score 2):

```
List @@@ {a + b, c + d}
testm = {Cos[a] + Sin[a], 5 + Sin[a]};
List @@@ testm
```

Whether is the following you want?

```
testm = {Cos[a] + Sin[a], 5 + Sin[a]};
m = List @@@ testm
Flatten[Table[{i.j, m[[i, j]]}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}], 1]
```

**Updated**

Maybe `MapIndexed` should work

```
 Clear["Global`*"];
testm = {a + b, c + d, e};
mat = List @@@ testm
Flatten[MapIndexed[f @@ {Dot @@ #2, #1} &, mat, {-1}]] /. 
  f -> List // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testm = {a + b, c + d, e};
index = StringTemplate[If[Length[#] == 2, "``.``", "``"]] @@ # &;
{index @ Position[testm, #, {-1}][[1]], #} & /@ Cases[testm, _Symbol, -1] // MatrixForm
```

---

**Update**

```
testm = {A Exp[I (k + l) m (n + o + p q)] Cos[r s] + A Exp[I (k + l) m (n + o + p q)] Sin[t u], c + d, e};
{index @ Position[testm, #, 2][[1]], #} & /@ Cases[testm, (_Symbol | _Times), 2] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for the simple example that I posted. However it does not work if I substitute for (a+b) a more complicated expression such as A exp(I(k+l)m(n+o+pq)) Cos(rs)+A exp(I(k+l)m(n+o+pq)) Sin(tu). I want this to be split up into the Cos and Sin terms.

Comment: @MrDerDart That means there are essential differences between your two cases and I just worked for your posted example.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: @MrDerDart Plz see my update.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[indexedMonomials]
indexedMonomials = Join @@
  (MapIndexed[{Dot @@ #2, #} &, MonomialList@#, {2}] /. {{a_, b_}} :> {{First@a, b}}) &;
```

***Example:***

```
testm2 = {A E^(I (k + l) m (n + o + p q)) Cos[r s] + 
    A E^(I (k + l) m (n + o + p q)) Sin[t u], a + b + x, c + d, e};

MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, testm2] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & A \cos (r s) e^{i m (k+l) (n+o+p q)}+A \sin (t u) e^{i m (k+l) (n+o+p q)} \\
>  2 & a+b+x \\
>  3 & c+d \\
>  4 & e \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
indexedMonomials @ testm2 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1.1 & A \cos (r s) e^{i m (k+l) (n+o+p q)} \\
>  1.2 & A \sin (t u) e^{i m (k+l) (n+o+p q)} \\
>  2.1 & a \\
>  2.2 & b \\
>  2.3 & x \\
>  3.1 & c \\
>  3.2 & d \\
>  4 & e \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$